# Cloud Code - containsString

Tags: parse-platform

I want to get all the rows that have a value of `like` or `dislike` in the column labeled: `type`. On my mobile code, I use `whereKey:"type" containsString:"like"` but I can't figure out how to do this in Cloud Code. I've searched for documentation, but I can't find any info on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I had difficulty finding this, so hopefully this will expedite the process for future searchers.

In Cloud Code, there's a function called `contains` that works the same as the function I mentioned.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Activity");
query.contains("type", "like");
query.equalTo("user", request.user);
query.equalTo("photo", request.object.get("photo"));
query.count({
    success: function(count) {
        //User has no activity on photo
        if(count == 0){
            response.success();
        }
        //User already has a like or dislike on photo
        else {
            response.error();
        } 
    },
    error: function() {
        response.error("like lookup failed");
    }
});
```